Is there a way to add SMTP addresses to Exchange Online using C#?
I'm searching for a way to add a new email address to a shared mailbox by C# running in an Azure Function. I cannot use any admin-account credentials, because we always enforce MFA. So, I was searching for an "Application permission" in Entry IDs App Registration UI, and "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite" seems the most promising to me, but the PATCH /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings documentation does not have any hints of additional SMTP addresses, so I assume: that's the wrong place to look for updating the "Email addresses".
I see that "admin.exchange.microsoft.com" uses https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/beta/Mailbox(123456789-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab) to update that list, but I cannot find any how to use that with an application registration instead of a user-login.
Are there examples of how to change shared mailbox email addresses without a user login, but with a service?

I think this article should help you to setup an app with a certificate that is allowed to access exchange. In this article you can find how to create a confidential client that is able to retrieve a valid token. Then in a last step you can use that token to authenticate your request before sending.

Thanks a lot for both articles. Now I need to find the documentation of the API (or reverse engineer the calls), but I think with the hint of the name of the permission (Exchange.ManageAsApp) that should be easier.

By using Fiddler you can inspect how the Powershell module used in this documentation will send REST calls. In essence you have to POST call https://outlook.office365.com/adminapi/beta/{_tenantId}/InvokeCommand with some header values and in the body provide the commandlet name and a dictionary with parameter names and values. You'll get back the result and maybe a nextLink if more then 1000 elements available. Chaining via pipe symbol is not possible.
